# Hibernate (JPA) inheritance mapping of abstract super classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My data model represents legal entities, such as a Business or a Person. Both are tax-paying entities, and both have a TaxID, a collection of phone numbers, and a collection of mailing addresses.

I have a Java model with two concrete classes that extend an abstract class. The abstract class has properties and collections that are common to both concrete classes.

```
AbstractLegalEntity        ConcreteBusinessEntity    ConcretePersonEntity
-------------------        ----------------------    --------------------
Set<Phone> phones          String name               String first
Set<Address> addresses     BusinessType type         String last
String taxId                                         String middle

Address                    Phone
-------                    -----
AbsractLegalEntity owner   AbstractLegalEntity owner
String street1             String number
String street2           
String city
String state
String zip
```

I'm using **<s>Hibernate</s> JPA Annotations** on a **MySQL** database, with classes like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractLegalEntity {
    private Long id;  // Getter annotated with @Id @Generated
    private Set<Phone> phones = new HashSet<Phone>();  // @OneToMany
    private Set<Address> address = new HashSet<Address>();  // @OneToMany
    private String taxId;
}

@Entity
public class ConcretePersonEntity extends AbstractLegalEntity {
    private String first;
    private String last;
    private String middle;
}

@Entity
public class Phone {
    private AbstractLegalEntity owner; // Getter annotated @ManyToOne @JoinColumn
    private Long id;
    private String number;
}
```

The problem is that `Phone` and `Address` objects need to refer to their owner, which is an `AbstractLegalEntity`. Hibernate complains:

```
@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on Phone references an unknown 
entity: AbstractLegalEntity
```

It seems like this would be a fairly common Java inheritance scenario, so I hope that Hibernate would support it. I've tried changing the mapping for AbstractLegalEntity based on a [Hibernate forum question](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=995294), no longer using `@MappedSuperclass`:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

However, now I get the following error. When reading up on this inheritance mapping type, it looks like I have to use SEQUENCE not IDENTITY, and MySQL doesn't support SEQUENCE.

```
Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> 
mapping for: ConcreteBusinessEntity
```

I'm making more progress toward getting things working when I use the following mapping.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
        name="entitytype",
        discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
```

I'm thinking I should continue down this path. My concern is that I'm mapping it as an `@Entity` when I really don't ever want an instance of AbstractLegalEntity to ever exist. I'd like to know if this is the right approach. What is the correct approach I should be taking for this situation?

Comment: you are using JPA annotations in hibernate, not hibernate annotations. That's an important distinction.

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - ah yes, that is correct. thanks for correcting it in my question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use:

```java
    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    AbstractLegalEntity
```

In the database you will have one table for `AbstractLegalEntity`, and tables for classes, which extend `AbstractLegalEntity` class. You won't have instances of `AbstractLegalEntity` if it's abstract. Polymorphism can be used here.

When you use:

```java
    @MappedSuperclass
    AbstractLegalEntity
    
    @Entity
    ConcretePersonEntity extends AbstractLegalEntity
```

This will create only one table in your database called `ConcretePersonEntity`, containing columns from both classes.

Comment: thanks, this helps clarify things. i was also able to use SINGLE_TABLE as well, which makes sense when I want fewer joins and there aren't tons of fields in the class hierarchy.

Comment: +1 I have a similar problem.  Are you willing to help me with it? In particular, I need help with both the DDL and the entity definitions.  I posted my code.  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252541/generatedvalue-for-a-java-abstract-superclass-over-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Add `@Entity` annotation to `AbstractLegalEntity`. Instance of `AbstractLegalEntity` will never exist - hibernate will load appropriate extending instances - `ConcreteBusinessEntity` or `ConcretePersonEntity` according to Id field.

Comment: A class CANNOT be marked as `@Entity` and `@MappedSuperClass` !

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `AbstracLegalEntity` as an `@Entity`. Even with the `@Entity` annotation, your class remains abstract. consequently, you will only have instance of concrete subclasses.