# Onetomany with parent database design

Tags: database, entity-relationship, one-to-many

Below is a database design which represents my problem(it is not my actual database design). For each city I need to know which restaurants, bars and hotels are available. I think the two designs speak for itself, but:

First design: create one-to-many relations between city and restaurants, bars and hotels.

Second design: only create an one-to-many relation between city and place.

Which design would be best practice? The second design has less relations, but would I be able to get all the restaurants, bars and hotels for a city and there own data (property_x/y/z)?

**Update: this question is going wrong, maybe my fault for not being clear.**

- the restaurant/bar/hotel classes are subclasses of "place" (in both
  designs).
- the restaurant/bar/hotel classes **must** have the parent "place"
- the restaurant/bar/hotel classes have there own specific data (property_X/Y/X)

[image: Database design]

Comment: Is that MySQL Workbench?

Comment: About the bounty: I decided to give it to Andrew because it seems the most complete answer. The other answers were also helpful, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Good design first**

Your data, and the **readability/understandability** of your SQL and ERD, are the most important factors to consider. For the purpose of readability:

- Put `city_id` into `place`. Why: Places are in cities. A hotel is not a place that *just happens* to be in a city by virtue of being a hotel.

Other design points to consider are how this structure will be extended in the future. Let's compare adding a new subtype:

- In design one, you need to add a new table, relationship to 'place' and a relationship to `city`
- In design two, you simply add a new table and relationship to 'place'.

I'd again go with the second design.

**Performance second**

Now, I'm guessing, but the reason for putting `city_id` in the subtype is probably that you anticipate that it's more efficient or faster in some specific use cases and this may be a very good reason to ignore readability/understandability. However, until you *measure* performance on the actual hardware you'll deploy on, you don't know:

- Which design is faster
- Whether the difference in performance would actually degrade the overall system
- Whether other optimization approaches (tuning SQL or database parameters) is actually a better way to handle it.

I would argue that design one is an attempt to physically model the database on an ERD, which is a bad practice.

*Premature* optimization is the root of a lot of evil in SW Engineering.

**Subtype approaches**

There are two solutions to implementing subtypes on an ERD:

1. A common-properties table, and one table per subtype, (this is your second model)
2. A single table with additional columns for subtype properties.

In the single-table approach, you would have:

- A subtype column, `TYPE INT NOT NULL`. This specifies whether the row is a restaurant, bar or hotel
- Extra columns `property_X`, `property_Y` and `property_Z` on `place`.

Here is a quick table of pros and cons:

Disadvantages of a single-table approach:

- The extension columns (X, Y, Z) cannot be NOT NULL on a single table approach. You can implement row-level constraints, but you lose the simplicity and visibility of a simple NOT NULL
- The single table is very wide and sparse, especially as you add additional subtypes. You may hit the max. number of columns on some databases. This can make this design quite wasteful.
- To query a list of a specific subtype, you have to filter using a `WHERE TYPE = ?` clause, whereas the table-per-subtype is a much more natural `FROM HOTEL INNER JOIN PLACE ON HOTEL.PLACE_ID = PLACE.ID"
- IMHO, mapping into classes in an object-oriented languages is harder and less obvious. Consider avoiding if this DB is going to be mapped by Hibernate, Entity Beans or similar

Advantages of a single-table approach:

- By consolidating into a single table, there are no joins, so queries and CRUD operations are more efficient (but is this small difference going to cause problems?)
- Queries for different types are *parameterized* (`WHERE TYPE = ?`) and therefore more controllable in code rather than in the SQL itself (`FROM PLACE INNER JOIN HOTEL ON PLACE.ID = HOTEL.PLACE_ID`).

*There is no best design*, you have to pick based on the type of SQL and CRUD operations you are doing most frequently, and possibly on performance (but see above for a general warning).

**Advice**

All things being equal, I would advise the default option is your second design. But, if you have an overriding concern such as those I listed above, do choose another implementation. But don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: yes. I would go with the 2nd design too. Plus I recommend to bring your database into the 3rd normal form (Database normalization). Then things can't go wrong, look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Comment: I use JPA to create the mappings. My concern with the second design is that "city" has an "one-to-many" mapping to "place(s)". If I want all the hotels in a city I would need to cast (some) places to hotels. Or I would need to create a (JPQL) query to find all the hotels for that city. In the first design "city" has a one-to-many mapping to "hotel(s)" directly.

Comment: @BigJ: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265454/hibernate-jpa-inheritance-mapping-of-abstract-super-classes @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) might help fix your JPA issues.

Comment: Yes, the one-to-many places mapping in city is using polymorphism. But to get all the hotels from that mapping I would still need to check the type (instanceof Hotel) and cast it. For instance to call hotel.getProperty_Z().

Comment: @BigJ: No, it's much better than that. You have '@Entity' on Hotel, so you can run the JPA query Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT h FROM Hotel h WHERE h.city.name = 'London'"); List<Hotel> londonHotels = q.getResultList(); Am I still missing something?

Comment: That is what I said in the second comment: a JPQL query would be necessary. In the first design, the City entity for "London" would have a List<Hotel> hotels mapping: no JPQL query is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them and none of them at all. 
If I need to choose one, I would keep the second one, because of the number of foreign keys and indexes needed to be created after. 
But, a better approach would be: create a table with all kinds of places (bars, restaurants, and so on) and assign to each row a column with a value of the type of the place (apply a *COMPRESS* clause with the types expected at the column). It would improve both performance and readability of the structure, plus being more easier to maintain.
 Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: I think your solution does not take into account that each type of place has its own data (property_x/y/z).

Answer (score 0):

you do not show alternate columns in any of the sub-place tables.  i think you should not split type data into table names like 'bar','restaurant', etc - these should be types inside the place table.

i think further you should have an address table - one column of which is city.  then each place has an address and you can easily group by city when needed. (or state or zip code or country etc)

Comment: I think he has different types of properties in each type of places as property_x int and property_y varchar etc

Comment: Oops, my bad. The comment was intended for Jose F. Sorry for my mistake

Comment: Actually spathirana, you are completely right. Both Randy and Jose F have overlooked the property_x/y/z columns in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is the second one. In the first design, there is a possibility of data errors as one place can be assigned to a particular restaurant (or any other type) in one city (e.g. A) and at the same time can be assigned to another restaurant in a different city (e.g. B). In the second design, a place is always bound to a particular city.

Comment: A place is not assigned to a restaurant: a restaurant is a subclass of a place. And, each restaurant is connected to 1 city.

Comment: In this case it is better if you could remove the place table and add the name and phone columns to each of those three subclasses. The joins are an overhead here.

Comment: Can you please explain why you insist that the places table is a MUST? because as I understand you do not necessarily need a parent class and sub class relationship in the db design as those are in java classes. If a given place is only associated with only one restaurant/bar/hotel and a place_id is mandatory for a restaurant/bar/hotel then you should not have a separate places table. Perhaps I am missing an important point here

Comment: A place is not only associated with one restaurant: a restaurant IS a place. Removing "place" would go against database normalization: duplicate data in the "restaurant/bar/hotel" tables. Also, I could add a column in "place" called "rank", which gives the ranking of a place.

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
Both designs can get you all the appropriate data.
**Second:**
If all extending classes are going to implement the location (which sound obvious for your implementation) then it would be a better practice to include it as part of the parent object. This would suggest option 2.
**Thingy:**
The thing is that even-tough you can find out the type of each particular PLACE, it is easier to just know that a type (CHILD) is always a place (PARENT). You can think of that while you visualize the result-set of option 2. With that in mind, I recommend the first approach.
**NOTE:**
First one doesn't have more relations, it just splits them.

Answer (score 0):

If bar, restaurant and hotel have different sets of attributes, then they are different entities and should be represented by 3 different tables. But why do you need the place table? My advice it to ditch it and have 3 tables for your 3 entities and that's that.

In code, collecting common attributes into a parent class is more organised and efficient than repeating them in each child class - of course. But as spathirana comments above, database design is not like OOP. Sure, you'll save on the repetition of column names by sticking common attributes of places into a "place" table. But it will also add complication:
- you have to join on that table whenever you want to reference a bar, restaurant or hotel
- you have to insert into two tables whenever you want to add a new bar, restaurant or hotel
- you have to update two tables when ... etc.

Having 3 tables without the place table is ALSO, PROBABLY, the most performance-optimal design. But that's not where I'm coming from. I'm thinking of clean, simple database design where a single entity means a single row in a single table. There are no "is-a" relationships in a relational DB. Foreign key relationships are "has-a". OK, there are exceptions I'm sure, but your case is not exceptional.

Comment: Removing "place" would go against database normalization: duplicate data in the "restaurant/bar/hotel" tables. Inserting/editing 2 tables (parent and child) is no extra work if you use JPA. It does effect performance a little bit.

Comment: It would duplicate column names, but not the data itself. Normalisation is about organising one-to-many relationships and has nothing to do with inheritance. Your design with the place table is no more - or less - normalised than the design I suggested.