# Mapping a polymorphic list with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, orm

Suppose I have:

```
//inheritance annotations 
public abstract class Animal {
    private int noOfLegs;
    //...
}

//inheritance annotations 
public class Cat extends Animal {
    //cat stuff
}

//inheritance annotations 
public class Dog extends Animal {
    //dog stuff
}

@Entity
public class House {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(//join stuff
    private List<Animal> animals;
    //hose stuff
}
```

Now if I put in my house both cats and dogs, and persist my house, does JPA know to put the dogs and cats in their corresponding tables (or whatever inheritance mapping strategy was used). Also does it know how to take it back when querying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes. But native hibernate support regarding inheritance mapping is more powerful than standard JPA, and "single table per class hierarchy" or "table per subclass" mapping strategies are more suitable for polymorphic queries and associations than "table per concrete class" strategy.

See also:

- [a relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265454/hibernate-jpa-inheritance-mapping-of-abstract-super-classes) with a JPA mapping example
- [hibernate inheritance mapping docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html)
- [hibernate inheritance strategies docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e3306)

Comment: Even though links to documentation may be useful solution of the problem would be probably appreciated as well.