# Generic method that accepts two types of List

Tags: java, list, generics, methods

I want to write a function that can accept two similar types. But not same.

```
MyClassA {
  abc()
  a2b()
}

MyClassB {
   abc()
   a3b()
}
```

One method is same in these two. The function should accept list of any of these two types and I want to invoke abc() on objects in the list.

This does not seem to help:

```
    private <T> Set<MyclassX> createObject(List<T> classes) {

          Set<MyclassX> x;

          if ( T instanceof MyClassA)  {
               for ( MyClassA a : classes ) {
                    if (a.abc().equals("somethig")) {
                         x.add( t.abc());
                     }   
                }   
           }
           return x;
     }
```

I don't even need to check `instanceof`. I just need to iterate through the list and compare the values. if there is a match, then call the method `abc()`

Comment: What happens when you compile and run your code? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Also please show the declaration for is `t`?

Comment: And what are the return types of the methods in your two classes.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to write two methods. But eclipse shows both are actually same. And yes, both methods accept List of differnt types. But list. So it does not allow.

Comment: Both return the same MyClassX

Comment: Please edit your Q to show this.

Comment: Type erasure means you don't have two different methods, you have the same method twice. List<Whatever> == List

Answer (score 8):

Just create a common interface and make MyClassA and MyClassB implement it:

```
interface MyClass {
    void abc();
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm.. these two are @Entity's. So I do not want to do that.

Comment: Or make an abstract super class, you can do it with @Entity, just take a look [mapped-superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265454/hibernate-jpa-inheritance-mapping-of-abstract-super-classes)

Comment: Please edit your question showing the `abstract` class solution.

Comment: If you cannot modify the classes, then generics does not fit in your case, as you don't have anything in common. To do what you proposed you can just use the class Object and then check `instanceof` as you are already doing. But if your objects are just entities, why do you have some logic in them? Or `abc` is just a getter? If that's the case I would go with the solution @KevinRave proposed.

Comment: interface should describe behaviour, myClass is not a good a name

Comment: @nachokk that's just an example. **Focus** on the main problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza examples should be clarificadores ;)

Comment: @nachokk it is pretty clear for OP, for author and at least 8 people who upvoted. By reading this code, there's no way to miss it. Again, **focus on the main problem**. And this example *es muy claro y conciso*.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `abstract super class` like this:

```
abstract SuperClass{
  abc();
  abstract ab(); // Only if the other methods share signatures
}

MyClassA extends SuperClass {
  ab();
}

MyClassB extends SuperClass{
  ab();
}

private <T> Set<? extends SuperClass> createObject(List<T> classes) {
   ...
}
```

If you only want to iterate over a collection that contains instances of `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`, then call the method `abc()` on those instances.
This can be work well with `JPA` because there is an annotation so called [MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) .

This way you can decompose the same logic from descendant classes in a way that fits with your requirements and can be used with generics. Here is a Hibernate example of [how to use](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/AbstractClassAsMappedSuperclass.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Using generics, you can do this:

```
private <T> Set<MyclassX> createObject(List<T> classes) {
    Set<MyclassX> x;
    for ( T a : classes ) {
        if (a.abc().equals("somethig")) {
            x.add( t.abc());
        }
    }
}
return x;
}
```

Assuming that `t.abc()` returns a `MyclassX`. (And I mean this literally, I'm not assuming that the `X` stands for something else.)

Comment: Erm, no ... you can't. Because there's no qualifier around `T` (meaning it's really `<T extends Object>`) that says it has a method `abc()`, and `Object` certainly doesn't have that method.

Comment: gah...I get Java generics mixed up with C++ templates too often ;-(

Comment: Without using an interface or classes derived from an abstract base you'd have to iterate through the List getting each thing as a T instance (or really, just as an Object) and check if it's an `instanceof` something then cast it. Which really is pointing at a poor design.

Comment: @BrianRoach Can you write an answer with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Type information can be passed in as an argument

```
<T> void method(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list)
{             
    if(clazz==MyClassA.class)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked)
        List<MyClassA> listA = (List<MyClassA>)list;
        ....
    }
    else if...
```

A better solution is probably to convert a `List<MyClassX>` to a `List<Abc>` before passing it in

```
interface ABC
    abc()

void method(List<Abc> list)
```

the conversion is probably going to be easy in java8

```
List<MyClassA> list1 = ...
method( list1.map( e->e.abc() ) );
```