# Hibernate - Inheritance Subclass cannot create tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, inheritance, jersey

I am trying to create RESTful webservice with a Hibernate Inheritance Mapping using annotations in Jersey. I have a
"User" as the superclass and "Admin" and "Customer" as the subclasses. I am sure that I have structured them as POJO. My hibernate configuration is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db</property>
    <property name="connection.username">dbuname</property>
    <property name="connection.password">dbpword</property>
    <property name="default_schema">db</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="com.company.artifact.model.User" />
    <mapping class="com.company.artifact.model.Admin" />
    <mapping class="com.company.artifact.model.Customer" />

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Below are my classes:

```
@Entity(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class User {
    //properties here

    //getters and setters here

    //constructor here
}

@Entity(name = "customer")
public class Customer extends User{
    //properties here

    //getters and setters here

    //constructor here
}

@Entity(name = "admin")
public class Admin extends User{
    //properties here

    //getters and setters here

    //constructor here
}
```

The problem is whenever I run the server and call a resource method to generate tables to my database I get the following error:

```
Apr 14, 2017 2:03:47 PM org.hibernate.AssertionFailure <init>
ERROR: HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in 
Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): 
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table db.user not found
Apr 14, 2017 2:03:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool 
[jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db]
Apr 14, 2017 2:03:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet 
[com.company.artifact.MyApplication] in context with path [/InheritanceApp] 
threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table db.user not found
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getTableId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5153)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.<init>(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:433)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:128)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:297)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:493)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
at com.company.artifact.util.SessionUtil.<init>(SessionUtil.java:21)
at com.company.artifact.util.SessionUtil.<clinit>(SessionUtil.java:10)
at com.company.artifact.dao.impl.BaseDaoImpl.openCurrentSession(BaseDaoImpl.java:27)
at com.company.artifact.service.impl.BaseCrudServiceImpl.get(BaseCrudServiceImpl.java:25)
at com.company.artifact.rest.service.impl.UserResourceServiceImpl.getUser(UserResourceServiceImpl.java:249)
at com.company.artifact.rest.UserResource.getUser(UserResource.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1452)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But when I remove the annotations for creating an Inheritance Mapping, the tables are being created but only the "User" class is being created at the database. Even when I create tables on my database manually it still return the same error that the table can't be found.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: suppose you have to remove `@Entity` and add `@MappedSuperclass` for the abstract class `User`. also you have to remove `<mapping class="com.company.artifact.model.User" />` from the mapping since it a abstract class and we are not going to create object using that class.

Comment: @Rajith Pemabandu I tried to add it but the error says that I cannot put MappedSuperClass on an entity, removing the entity annotation the error now I get is "Unable to locate persister: com.company.artifact.model.User"

Comment: this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827494/inherited-abstract-class-with-jpa-hibernate) may be helpful. also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265454/hibernate-jpa-inheritance-mapping-of-abstract-super-classes) might be a solution.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu I removed it but still it returned the same error. Also, the structure of my database tables must have a User table since the subclasses only have specific properties that differ from each other.

Comment: then you have to remove the `abstract` keyword from your User class. After that set `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` in hibernate configurations and try run the project.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu on the links you sent using MappedSuperclass will make the class not be created on the database but the properties will be inherited by the subclasses.

Comment: yes. It won't create a table in the database as it is abstract.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu I removed the abstract in my User class I still get the same error.